# How should we salvage the etymology question, if at all?

Tags: discussion

This question was originally closed as too broad: [What do Kerf, Dado, Rabbet, Tenon and Mortise mean?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/1736/49)

It has been edited to reduce the scope, but now I think the wording does not achieve what the author intended, and opens the question up to basic dictionary definitions which were already present in the original question's linked reference. Another issue is that the question just lists a small arbitrary set of terms which is presently useful for the author but won't necessarily be useful for future visitors.

<strike>I think if we are to reopen this question at all, it may only make sense to do so by converting it to a community wiki, in which case we could produce a list of terms in the question and have one answer per term.</strike>

I'm struggling to find a way to salvage the question I'm beginning to wonder if it really is on-topic here. I think most etymology answers would be very short like the ones in the existing answer to that question. I would be hesitant to give the go-ahead for someone to go down a long list of woodworking terms and submit a question for the etymology of each one. It seems English.SE would be much more appropriate for that, or the etymology should really be rolled into questions like, "What is a dado?"

Does it make sense to salvage the question, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

The types of complete answers that we would want would be at least a few paragraphs long, and the best ones would include diagrams and pictures. If we had just one question with a number of answers, I think it would be difficult to sort through the list of answers to find the description of the term you're looking for.

I think this topic is best served by having separate questions for each terms (perhaps combining rabbit and dado as well as mortise and tenon, though I'm not sure).

As an aside, it looks like the author got confused from the comments and removed the part asking for etymologies. The question is on hold because it is too broad, not because it is off topic. I think asking about etymologies on woodworking terms is on topic, and would be a good thing to include if the question was broken up into specific terms.

Comment: Good points. I was one of the people who closed the question as "too broad" but now that I'm struggling to find a way to salvage the question I'm beginning to wonder if it really *is* on-topic here. I think most etymology answers would be very short like the ones in the existing answer to that question. I would be hesitant to give the go-ahead for someone to go down a long list of woodworking terms and submit a question for the etymology of each one. It seems English.SE would be much more appropriate for that, or the etymology should really be rolled into questions like, "What is a dado?"